# Asp.net web page showing Event code: 3005 unhandled exception.application deployed in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have deployed my .net web appliation was working in windows server but when I moved to windows server 2008 r2. only two pages in my site is throughing exception  fro every 10 to 15 mins. These pages are working perfect some time and then suddenly throwing excpetion like follows

```
3005 
   An unhandled exception has occurred. 
   9/12/2012 2:48:22 AM 
   9/12/2012 6:48:22 AM 
   8e88fffed9bd4edeb5a2a9c94ba189f8 
   8 
   1 
   0 
   /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-1-129919060903353364 
   Full w3wp.exe 
   NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
   FileLoadException 
   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=945cb50e7342eb4c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) at System.Web.UI.AssemblyCache.GetAjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute(Assembly assembly) at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_DefaultAjaxFrameworkAssembly() at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager..ctor() at ASP.pages_claims_referralform_aspx.__BuildControlScriptClaims
```

and my IIS details are

Framework veriosn is 4.0
IIS version is 7.5.7600

Comment: FileLoadException Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.1.0.0, .......The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference did ou try to take alook at the assemblies manifest

Comment: yes, the same thing is working fine if I set the defaultappppol for my web application . this errror is coming only if chaged to My application's newly created application pool.